# Testing RX observable with Xunit

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to unit test a reactive observable within my xunit tests but i'm stuck.

my observable which runs UpdateJob() function for infinite times and once found a new job, it publishes it.

```
    private IObservable<long> _jobQueue;
    public IJob CurrentJob;

    private async void SetupObservable()
    {
        _jobQueue= Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(UpdateJob))                
            .Concat()
            .Do(gotNewJob =>
            {
                if (gotNewJob)
                    _logger.Information("some info");
            })
            .Where(gotNewJob => gotNewJob == true) // only accept new jobs.
            .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
            .Publish()
            .RefCount();
    }

    protected override async Task<bool> UpdateJob()
    {
          CurrentJob = new Job();
          CurrentJob.Status = "OK";
          return true;
    }
```

then in my unit tests, i'd like to get first 2 results and then compare them to my expected values using fluentassertions.

```
    [Fact]
    public async void Test1()
    {
          await SetupObservable(); 

        var test2 = _jobQueue.Take(2)
            .Subscribe(x =>
            {
               CurrentJob.Status.ShouldBeEquivalentTo("OK");
            });
    }
```

But couldn't get this working. Tried something like this too

```
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var results = scheduler.CreateObserver<MoneroJob>();


        var testObserver = scheduler.Start(x => _
        {
            _jobQueue.Select(unit => unit).Subscribe(results);
        }, 0,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks);


        var test = results.Messages;
```

but still no luck. any ideas?

Comment: Your code as written makes no sense: `_jobQueue` is of type `IObservable<Unit>` which doesn't have a property `Status`. Function `Setup` is type `void` but you're awaiting it (which is technically allowed, but serves no purpose here and is not recommended). Please update your code to better represent your problem.

Comment: done so to make the code more readable.

Comment: Your code as modified still does not compile. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @HuseyinUslu - Why do you have `.Publish().RefCount()`? It make no sense in your current code and could lead to bugs in the future if you make changes to the way you are using it.

Comment: @HuseyinUslu - You've used the word "infinitive" (which means "having or involving the basic form of a verb"). Did you mean "infinite"?

Answer (score 0):

The following code-dump works and appears to pass the tests in LinqPad. It appears to me to be a working equivalent to your non-compiling code. Having said that, I have no idea what you're intending to accomplish or test:

```
//Add NuGet packages xunit, System.Reactive, FluentAssertions

async void Main()
{
    SetupObservable();

    var test2 = _jobQueue.Take(2)
        .Subscribe(x =>
        {
            CurrentJob.Status.ShouldBeEquivalentTo("OK");
            Console.WriteLine(CurrentJob.Status); //Ouptuts "OK" and "OK" as expected
        });
}
public IObservable<Unit> _jobQueue;
public Logger _logger = new Logger();
public IJob CurrentJob;

// Define other methods and classes here
public async void SetupObservable()
{
    _jobQueue = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
        .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(UpdateJob))
        .Concat()
        .Do(gotNewJob =>
        {
            if (gotNewJob)
                _logger.Information("some info");
        })
        .Where(gotNewJob => gotNewJob == true) // only accept new jobs.
        .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();
}

public async Task<bool> UpdateJob()
{
    CurrentJob = new Job();
    CurrentJob.Status = "OK";
    return true;
}

public interface IJob {
    string Status { get; set;}
}

public class Job : IJob
{
    public string Status { get; set;}
}

public class Logger
{
    public void Information(string s) {}
}
```

Comment: I think this is only working in LINQPad because the run-time environment allows the background threads to keep running. In a proper test environment this would probably fail.

Answer (score 0):

There was a slight issue with Shlomo's code where the test would fail in a test environment that ended the test before the subscription could fire. Here's how to properly avoid that:

```
async void Main()
{
    SetupObservable();

    var test2 =
        await
            _jobQueue
                .Take(2)
                .Do(x =>
                {
                    CurrentJob.Status.ShouldBeEquivalentTo("OK");
                    Console.WriteLine(CurrentJob.Status); //Ouptuts "OK" and "OK" as expected
                })
                .ToArray();
}

public void SetupObservable()
{
    _jobQueue =
        Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .SelectMany(_ => Observable.FromAsync(UpdateJob))
            .Where(gotNewJob => gotNewJob == true) // only accept new jobs.
            .Do(gotNewJob => _logger.Information("some info"))
            .Select(_ => Unit.Default);
}
```

(And I've also cleaned up your query too.)

It's tested and works.